Quickest way to iterate over a pandas dataframe and perform an operation on a column, when what the operation is depends on the row
I have a table that is laid out somewhat like this:



t
linenum
many other columns




1234567
0
...


1234568
0
...


1234569
0
...


1234570
1
...


1234571
1
...



Except it is very, very large. As in, the raw .dat files can get up to 20 gb. I have them converted into .h5 files so they are slightly smaller, but still large (about half the size, I'd say.)
I want to add a column that is time within line, so it subtracts the first time value for the line from each time, so I end up having something like this:



t
linenum
time within line




1234567
0
0


1234568
0
1


1234569
0
2


1234570
1
0


1234571
1
1



The thing is, while I know that doing an operation on the whole dataframe at once is much faster, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this without using a for loop, since the number that needs to be subtracted depends on linenum, and it takes ages. (Yesterday, I tested this on a file about 9gb big, and I gave up and went home after it had been processing for half an hour, only to find this morning that my computer had restarted overnight so the jupyter server had to restart and I lost the processed dataframe...) Here is the relevant parts of the code I currently have:
import pandas as pd
file = [h5 file address]
df = pd.read_hdf(file)
for linenum in pd.unique(df['linenum']):
  line_df = df.loc[df['linenum'] == linenum]
  first_t = int(line_df['t'].iloc[0])
  df.loc[df['linenum'] == linenum, 't_adjusted'] = (df.loc[df['linenum'] == linenum, 't'] - first_t)

Is there any way to do this without a for loop, and if not, is there any way to make it faster? I'm trying to graph one of the other columns using matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf, with linenum on the x axis and time within line on the y axis, if that's relevant at all. There is another column I can use as a workaround because it's approximately proportional to time within line but I'd prefer to find a way to use the time. Thank you!
Edit: Also, if it's relevant, I am using Python 3.7. For some reason some of the computers my programs have to run on at my work are still on Windows 7 so I can't update...

can it be that the time point with which we take the difference can be positioned extremely far from the point in question? for example linenum 0 could be occuring say at index 0 and possibly at index 1 million as well? Otherwise, we can take an approach such as chunking thr dataframe. Moreover, is memory a concern?

@rasengan__ The times are sorted from smallest to largest, the line numbers also are sorted from smallest to largest as they are created sequentially. James' answer below worked perfectly for me. Memory is a concern in that these files are huge, able to get up to 20gb when my computer has only 16gb ram, but there is another computer with more memory that I can remote into and work on if necessary. Ideally I don't need to though because my coworker wants to be able to use my program for data analysis even on the large files

You can use a groupby on 'linenum' and then transform to populate each group
df['timewithinline'] = df.groupby('linenum')['t'].transform(lambda x: x - min(x))

If the times are already sorted, you can use:
df['timewithinline'] = df.groupby('linenum')['t'].transform(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])


Thank you! I had never used groupby or transform before, those look very useful. (I've done quite a bit of data manipulation with pandas, but still only really the bare basics.) My program is currently tied up trying to graph things but I'll give this a try once it's done and see if it is able to do it in a reasonable time!

Oh my god, that took only about a minute. Thank you so, so much.

James' answer is better, but if working with sequential data you could group by linenum and then use .cumcount():
import pandas as pd
df['time within line'] = df.groupby('linenum').cumcount()

This only works if each time is sequential.

You're right my bad. I'll keep it but put a disclaimer.

I don't actually know if the times always increase by the same amount. I know they're sorted smallest to largest; when I found a very small file for initial testing the times went up by 10 each, but I don't know if that's always true.
